# How to use wxChartDir inside a frame for contour plot in wxWidgets application?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to build an application for comparing the data from different simulations,by displaying the data in the form of contour plots/surface plots in my wxWidgets application.I have searched online and in a forum I find that wxChartDir serves the purpose.
But I am unable to figure out how to use install that library and use in my applications.
If any one has an idea please help me as my project heart lies with the plots.
I also couldn't find any sample applications using wxChartDir to figure it out on my own.

Comment: The autor of wxCharDir used to be active at [wx forum](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

wxChartDir comes with **all** samples of the ChartDirector distribution ported to wxWidgets. Among them several which embed a chart/plot in a wxFrame. This should really give you enough examples, how wxChartDir can be used.

If you still experience problems after having studied the samples' code, you may open an issue on the [wxChartDir issue tracker](https://github.com/utelle/wxchartdir/issues).